# Lock screen Buttons disappeared

Tags: insider-preview, wifi, lock-screen, cellular

I am using Microsoft Lumia 540. I updated my Lumia with insider updates from fast ring. Now my phone is showing three problems.

1. Lock screen buttons are disappeared, that's why I am unable to input 4 digit PIN.
2. Not connecting with WI-FI.
3. Not connecting with Cellular Network.

When I connect my phone with charger it automatically shutdowns and starts again and again.

How can I roll back from this update without signing in?
OR is there any way to sign in without accessing lock screen???

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This issue is fixed in the build 14936. Here is what it says,

> - We fixed the issue causing the pin pad to not be visible to unlock the
>     phone even after rebooting the phone.
> - We fixed the issue where some phones lose the ability to use their SIM cards.

---

Reference:

1. [Windows 10 build 14936 rolling out for fast ring insiders](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-build-14936-rolling-out-fast-ring-insiders).